# "Web of science" as search provider in chrome?

Tags: literature-search, tools, web-of-science

Is it possible to use Web of Science from the Chrome Omni-Bar (aka address-bar)?

Chrome supports adding custom searches by mapping a string to a search expression, e.g.

```
i    https://www.google.at/search?tbm=isch&q=%s
doi  https://dx.doi.org/%s
```

which then allows entering `doi XXXX.XXXX` to lookup a doi, or `i academia` to do a google image search for "academia".

[apps.webofknowledge.com](https://apps.webofknowledge.com) however, has session-based urls where the current query isn't included in any readable form, so this method won't work. They do provide a [description of how to add web of science as search provider](http://wokinfo.com/webtools/browsersearch/) but it seems to be outdated by years – Chrome isn't even mentioned and it doesn't work in Internet Explorer 11 either.

Answer (score 1):

Could this Chrome extension be of use to you:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-of-science-quick-sear/nemobobcigeaigadamdpegpjkklkoeae?hl=en

Just click Add to Chrome and you should be jamming.

Comment: I noticed that the extension is provided by Clarivate Analytics, the owner of Web of Science, so it should be compatible for now and the future.

Comment: I have that one installed already. Since it doesn't integrate with the Omni bar, it gives no big advantage over navigating to the website. Better than nothing, but still inferior to Omni bar integration.